# Allow numbers in regex including the negative

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, negative-number

I have written this regex to remove any thing which is not number.

```
     var dataTest = data.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
```

It converts "abc123xyz" to "123"

However now i want to cover negative numbers also :-

```
      var dataTest = data.replace(/[^-0-9]/gi, '');
```

But it is allowing - in between also.
It converts "abc123-xyz" to "123-"
I want it to convert to "123"

However, if user gives "-123abc" , it should change to "-123".

I am invoking this code on focusout event in javascript. I will accept solution in jquery also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to capture the number and remove everything else:

```js
input = "abc-123def"

clean = input.replace(/.*?(-?\d+).*/, "$1")

document.write(clean)
```

or, more efficiently, with `match`:

```
 clean = (input.match(/-?\d+/) || [])[0]
```